# ref does not exist on container component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-forwardref

I'm trying to call a function from a child component through a Connected Component (Container) from the parent.

When I try to reference the child component I get the error `Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<{ results: {}[]; }, never>'.`

Sorry for the wall of code that's about to follow, I tried to trim the code as much as possible.

Here's the parent component:

```
imports...

class App extends React.Component {
    searchBoxRef = createRef<SearchBox>();

    resetTextBox() {
        console.log("It's happening!")

        // if (this.searchBoxRef.current) {
        //     this.searchBoxRef.current.clearInput();
        // }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="grid-container">
                    <div className="header">
                        <SearchBoxContainer ref={this.searchBoxRef} />
                    </div>
                    <FacetboxContainer resetAll={this.resetTextBox} />
                    <ResultsContainer/>
                </div>
            </div >
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

The container component:

```
imports...

function getReturnType<RT>(expression: (...params: any[])=>RT): RT {
    return {} as RT;
}          

declare type SearchDispatchActions = FacetsAction | SuggestionsAction | InputAction

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: redux.Dispatch<SearchDispatchActions>) => {
    return {
        *dispatch items*
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: Store.SearchState) {
    return {
        *props*
    }
}

export const stateProps = getReturnType(mapStateToProps);
export const dispatchProps = getReturnType(mapDispatchToProps);

export type PropsType = typeof stateProps & typeof dispatchProps;
type State = {};

const SearchBoxContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { forwardRef: true })(SearchBox);

export { SearchBoxContainer }
```

And finally here's the Searchbox component

```
imports...

export type State = {
  searchInput: string;
};

class SearchBox extends React.Component<PropsType, State> {
  constructor(props: PropsType) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchInput: "" };
  }

  private searchRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  ...

  render() {
    ...

    return (
        ...
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBox;
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were concerned about posting too much code, but I actually think you haven't provided enough! I'm not sure how you are executing the `clearInput()` and why you need a ref to the `HTMLInputElement` inside `SearchBox` at all, since I would think that you would clear the input by setting `state.searchInput`.

### With Refs

> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<{ results: {}[]; }, never>'.

This error tells you that you cannot pass the prop `ref` to the component `SearchBox` because `ref` is not defined as a prop.  You can either:

1. allow `SearchBox` to take a `ref` prop by creating a `ForwardRefExoticComponent` with the `forwardRef` function.
2. pass a `RefObject` under any other prop name.

If the ultimate ref is to an `HTMLInputElement`, you can create the ref in `App` and pass it down through a prop called `inputRef`.

```
inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
```

```
<SearchBoxContainer inputRef={this.inputRef} />
```

```
export type PropsType = typeof stateProps & typeof dispatchProps & {
  inputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>
}
```

But if we start manipulating the `value` of the input directly from `App` when the value is also controlled by the `state` of `SearchBox`, you'll start to see why this is a bad design pattern.

### Without Refs

Why don't we ditch the refs entirely and [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) of the input text up into `App`?  Now `SearchBox` has no component state, and it handles everything through props `text` and `onChangeText`.

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  state = { searchInput: "" };

  resetTextBox() {
    console.log("It's happening!");
    this.setState({ searchInput: "" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="grid-container">
          <div className="header">
            <SearchBoxContainer
              text={this.state.searchInput}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ searchInput: text })}
            />
          </div>
          <FacetboxContainer resetAll={this.resetTextBox} />
          <ResultsContainer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
export type PropsType = typeof stateProps & typeof dispatchProps & {
  text: string;
  onChangeText(text: string): void;
};

class SearchBox extends React.Component<PropsType> {
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        value={this.props.text}
        onChange={(e) => this.props.onChangeText(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for revisiting an old question and taking your time with the answer. In the end I added the ref as a prop to the component. I didn't think I have to to that because I thought that every react component has a _ref_ like it has a _key_

Comment: `ref` is a special prop, so in order to set a ref and have it be passed down you need to use `forwardRef` on the child.  If you name it anything else then you can just access it as a normal prop.